# How to make ng-disbaled worked using Kendo grid?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

I applied ng-disabled on hyperlink in below kendo template, but its not working i tried with ng-show and ng-hide these angularJs directives are working... I read there is an issue raised for IE 10 and below .. Please let me know if there is any alternate solution ?

config.js

```
function displayChallengeKeys(dataItem) {
                            var returnData = '';
                            if(!!dataItem.challengeKeys){
                                dataItem.challengeKeys.forEach(function(challengeKey){
                                    returnData= returnData+ '<a href=""  ng-click="editChallenge('+challengeKey+',Y)" ng-disabled="dataItem.riskAssessmentStatus === \'RA_ASES_FINAL\'"><span require-control-point="CHALLENGES_VIEW">'+challengeKey+'</span></a>, ';
                                  });
                            }
```

grid.js

```
{
                                            field : 'challengeKeys',
                                            title : 'Challenge # <br>if created',
                                            template: displayChallengeKeys

                                        }
```

Comment: Try using two equal signs `==` instead of three `===`

Comment: Also, please format your code, it looks really bad. You have a preview window below the edit text when you ask your question, just remove the whitespace so everything is indented correct.

Comment: == signs did not work..

Comment: Is dataItem available from the scope in the rendered result?

Comment: yes dataItem is available